# Monkey patching in new and already imported modules

Tags: python

I have 3 files in the same directory:

```
# foo.py (my source code, I can make changes here)
def patched_f_bar():
    print('patched_f_bar')
import bar
import baz
bar.f_bar = patched_f_bar
bar.f_bar()
baz.f_baz()
```

```
# baz.py (library, I can't change this)
from bar import f_bar
def f_baz():
    print('from baz:')
    f_bar()
    print('from baz.')
```

```
# bar.py (library, I can't change this)
def f_bar():
    print("f_bar")
```

I am calling `python foo.py` with the hope to replace function `f_bar` defined in `bar.py` with `patched_f_bar`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for calls from other modules.

```
patched_f_bar
from baz:
f_bar          # expected: patched_f_bar
from baz.
```

This issue can be fixed by reordering `import baz` and `bar.f_bar = patched_f_bar` in `foo.py`:

```
patched_f_bar
from baz:
patched_f_bar      # as expected
from baz.
```

I am looking for a general solution to do such monkey patching without relying on the order of imports. After patching, I expect all calls from any module to be redirected to the new function.

Comment: Look into using a singleton. That way if you update the singleton it will affect everything

Comment: @testfile I know it is a bad practice, but I am trying to patch the code existing library that I can't change. I can't insert singleton in the library implementation, unfortunately.

Comment: Write a new module/package with the appropriate patch and use that instead of the original library.

Answer (score 1):

All works as expected. Let us see what happens under the hood:

Nothing special in foo for the beginning of your code:

```
# foo.py (my source code, I can make changes here)
def patched_f_bar():
    print('patched_f_bar')
import bar
import baz
```

Now at `baz` import time

```
# baz.py (library, I can't change this)
from bar import f_bar  # here is the point
def f_baz():
    print('from baz:')
    f_bar()
    print('from baz.')
```

You do not simply import the `bar` module. `from bar import f_bar` actually creates a variable in `baz` pointing to the **current** `f_bar` function of `bar`

Let us go on:

```
bar.f_bar = patched_f_bar    # patches f_bar IN BAR MODULE
bar.f_bar()                  # calls the patched function
baz.f_baz()
```

but `baz.f_baz` will still use the *cached* version, meaning here the original function.

You must patch the function in `baz` module as well, because it contains a `from ... import ...`:

```
...
bar.f_bar = patched_f_bar
baz.f_bar = patched_f_bar
bar.f_bar()
baz.f_baz()   # it now calls the patched version!
```

The bad news is that it may be hard to guess the import model used by a third party module. If it used:

```
from bar import f_bar as bar_f_bar
```

you would have to patch it that way:

```
baz.bar_f_bar = patched_f_bar
```

because the rule is that all references in the third party module must point directly (like above) or indirectly (if it just imported the `bar` module) to your patched function.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. Now I am wondering if it is possible to iterate over all already imported modules and check each imported symbol if it refers to the module that I am trying to patch.